# Not all data in a column is being copied to another csv file

Tags: python, csv, reader

So I have two csv files. One is in the following format:

```
last name, first name, Number
```

The other is in this format:

```
number, quiz
```

I want to create a new output file that takes these two csv files and gives me a file in the following format:

```
last name, first name, number, quiz.
```

I have tried the follwoing code and it works, but only for the first person listed in the first two input files. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Also, I do not want to assume that the two input files follow the same order.

```
import sys, re
import numpy as np
import smtplib
from random import randint
import csv
import math

col = sys.argv[1]
source = sys.argv[2]
target = sys.argv[3]
newtarg = sys.argv[4]


input_source = csv.DictReader(open(source))
input_target = csv.DictReader(open(target))
data = {}
t = ()

for row in input_target:
    t = row['First Name'], row['number']
    for rows in input_source:
        if rows['number'] == row['number']:
            t = t + (rows[col],)
            name = row['Last Name']
            data[name] = [t]
            rows.next()
        row.next()


with open(newtarg,'w') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    for key, val in data.items():
        csv_out.writerow([key] + list(val))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a job for [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), the Python Data Analysis Library:

```
import pandas as pd

x1 = pd.read_csv('x1.csv')
x2 = pd.read_csv('x2.csv')
result = pd.merge(x1, x2, on='number')
result.to_csv('result.csv',
              index=False,
              columns=['Last Name', 'First Name', 'number', 'quiz'])
```

Reference: https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html

Comment: Okay I think I have it working nicely My only question is when I merge the files. I am getting a column separating the merge

Comment: @Kate That's probably because you have an extra column in your first input file. See my recent edit for the `columns=` parameter to `.to_csv()`. This way, you explicitly control which columns are printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work. **Note:** I've taken out all the stuff in the code in your question that's not being used (as you should have done before posting it). I've also hardcoded the input values for testing.

```
import csv

source = 'source1.csv'
target = 'target1.csv'
newtarg = 'new_output.csv'

targets = {}
with open(target) as file:
    for row in csv.DictReader(file):
        targets[row['number']] = row['quiz']

with open(source) as src, open(newtarg, 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(src)
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(reader.fieldnames + ['quiz'])  # create a header row (optional)
    for row in reader:
        row.update({'quiz': targets.get(row['Number'], 'no match')})
        writer.writerow(row.values())
```

Comment: This gave me an output file with only the numbers

Comment: Kate: If you would edit your question and added several sample lines from each of the two input files, I may be able to fix that—I created and used my own input files for testing the code in my answer (and it appeared  to work correctly). What version of Python are you using. The code in my answer was written for Python 3.x.